# Set Ubuntu Sound Volume on boot

Tags: ubuntu, audio, volume

The Ubuntu startup/login sound can be very loud, but I do like having it. I wrote a script that uses amixer to set the volume to 25%. This is the level I like to have it at, but when I use TV out or headphones I have to turn up the volume. I cannot seem to get the script to run before the login sound plays. I have tried a cron @reboot, and putting a symlink to the script in /etc/rc3.d/, and in my .bash_profile script.  Only the 3rd method actually sets the volume correctly, but after the login sound plays.

Ideally I want to have the script run when I am logging out for the night, or just before the ubuntu login screen displays.

Here is the command to set the volume:

```
`/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 sset Master,0 25% > /dev/null`
```

Suggestions for other methods to try are appreciated.

Comment: Similar question: http://askubuntu.com/a/136832/75050 (more recent answer, worked for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try adding that line to your like to `/etc/rc.local`   This may not be soon enough though, since rc.local will be called after gdm.

Also note, the default runlevel on Ubuntu is **2**, not **3**.  Your link in rc3.d probably didn't work simply because you where not using runlevel 3.  The default runlevel is setup by /etc/event.d/rc-default

Comment: This method stopped functioning for me in Ubuntu 9.04, and in 9.10. Have not yet tried in 10.04

Comment: Adding it to runlevel 2 worked only partial for me. This sound I hear when I can enter the Password is now at 25% volume, but after I logged in it is at the same sound volume as it had when I shut the computer down. I created the symlink with `sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/sound.sh /etc/rc2.d/S20sound`, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Ubuntu's startup scripts already include an "alsactl restore".  You should be able to run "alsactl store" with the volume already set to 25% and affect all future reboots.

Comment: This is the method that worked for me, on Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, yes, but do they also contain an "alsactl store" on shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

Rob,

I am trying to solve the same issue. I took you "amixer" line above and did alot of poking around learning about runlevels, the /etc/rc#.d folders and the update-rc.d command. It's not perfect. It still doesn't run during a restart the way I would want it to, but its a start.

Suggestions to improve it would would be welcome.

And, here is my code below.....

sudo echo "#!/bin/bash" > /etc/init.d/lowvol.sh

sudo echo "/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 sset Master,0 35% > /dev/null" >> /etc/init.d/lowvol.sh

sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/lowvol.sh

sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/lowvol.sh

sudo update-rc.d lowvol.sh stop 20 0 6 .

Comment: Unfortunately I never solved this issue after updating Ubuntu to a new version. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Create a unit configuration and enable it for startup.

Assuming ALSA and systemd (Ubuntu uses systemd version after 14 onwards)

## `/etc/systemd/system/alsavolume.service`

Create a unit file here. You can adjust the command to run `/usr/bin/amixer sset PCM -- 97%`. Remember not to use quotations (otherwise systemd will interpret the whole thing as a command).

```
[Unit]
Description="Set volume level."
After=sound.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/amixer sset PCM -- 97%

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable it (this means creating a symbolic link to `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants` to run at startup, but the following commands take care of it for you.)

1. Reload daemons

   `systemctl daemon-reload`
2. Enable service

   `systemctl enable alsavolume.service`

   You can add the parameter `--now` to run the unit immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ALSA#Restore_ALSA_Mixer_settings_at_startup) method to achieve that before, but on Arch Linux. Now, I'm not too familiar with the init system Ubuntu uses, but I guess you could try adapting this to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to write a script to lower down your volume when you shut down your computer.
Something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

amixer -- sset Master playback -40dB

exit 1
```

then run this script at shutdown.